# Why does my openshift app timeout when I try to access the URL?

Tags: openshift, connection-timeout, browserquest

I am trying to set up a [BrowserQuest](http://browserquest.mozilla.org/) server that runs in openshift

I've been following [this](https://github.com/browserquest/BrowserQuest/blob/master/README.md) readme.  Everything seems to go fine, I get to the end and run `rhc app show bq` and get the following output:

```
bq @ http://bq-plantagenet.rhcloud.com/ (uuid: 55e4311189f5cf028d0000fc)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Domain:     plantagenet
Created:    8:18 AM
Gears:      1 (defaults to small)
Git URL:    ssh://55e4311189f5cf028d0000fc@bq-plantagenet.rhcloud.com/~/git/bq.git/
SSH:        55e4311189f5cf028d0000fc@bq-plantagenet.rhcloud.com
Deployment: auto (on git push)

nodejs-0.10 (Node.js 0.10)
--------------------------
Gears: Located with smarterclayton-redis-2.6

smarterclayton-redis-2.6 (Redis)
--------------------------------
From:    http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart
Website: https://github.com/smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart
Gears:   Located with nodejs-0.10
```

But when I try to access http://bq-plantagenet.rhcloud.com:8080/ in a browser, I get:

```
The connection has timed out
The server at bq-plantagenet.rhcloud.com is taking too long to respond
```

My questions are what is going wrong and how can I fix it?  Many thanks for your consideration in reading through this and any suggestions you might have for resolving it

Answer (score 1):

You need to access http://bq-plantagenet.rhcloud.com, leave off the port 8080, that is the port you listen on internally.  You should also try checking your log files (https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html) to see what errors your application is producing.